# How to use ZF2 Modules in Expressive?

Tags: php, zend-framework, mezzio

I have a module in ZF2 (MVC), now can config to re-use with [Expressive Middleware](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-expressive/)?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the dependencies in the module you can reuse a module in Expressive with [zend-component-installer](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-component-installer) and [zend-config-aggregator](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-config-aggregator). I suggest using the [zend-expressive-skeleton](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive-skeleton) to set it up.